# How I can change text color for every 5 first words in label?

Tags: swift, uilabel, uicolor

I get different text from API and I want change text color for every 5 first word. I try use range and attributes string, but I do something wrong and this not good work for me. How can i do it?

this is my code:

```
private func setMessageText(text: String) {
    let components = text.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let words = components.filter { !$0.isEmpty }

    if words.count >= 5 {
        let attribute = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: text)

        var index = 0
        for word in words where index < 5 {

            let range = (text as NSString).range(of: word, options: .caseInsensitive)
            attribute.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: Colors.TitleColor, range: range)
            attribute.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: Fonts.robotoBold14, range: range)
            index += 1
        }
        label.attributedText = attribute
    } else {
        label.text = text
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDm2v.png)

Comment: [edit] your question to include the actual code causing the issue in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: added. Sorry for don't do it earlier

Comment: What do you mean by “every 5 first word”? Every fifth word? The first five words? The first five occurrences of the first word? Every fifth occurrence of the first word? Can you edit your question and clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more efficient to get the index of the end of the 5th word and add color and font once for the entire range.

And you are strongly discouraged from bridging `String` to `NSString` to get a subrange from a string. **Don't do that**. Use native Swift `Range<String.Index>`, there is a convenience API to convert `Range<String.Index>` to `NSRange` reliably.

```
private func setMessageText(text: String) {
    let components = text.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let words = components.filter { !$0.isEmpty }

    if words.count >= 5 {
        let endOf5thWordIndex = text.range(of: words[4])!.upperBound
        let nsRange = NSRange(text.startIndex..<endOf5thWordIndex, in: text)

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        attributedString.addAttributes([.foregroundColor : Colors.TitleColor, .font : Fonts.robotoBold14], range: nsRange)
        label.attributedText = attributedString
    } else {
        label.text = text
    }
}
```

An alternative – more sophisticated – way is to use the dedicated API `enumerateSubstrings(in:options:` with option `byWords`

```
func setMessageText(text: String) {

    var wordIndex = 0
    var attributedString : NSMutableAttributedString?
    text.enumerateSubstrings(in: text.startIndex..., options: .byWords) { (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop) in
        if wordIndex == 4 {
            let endIndex = substringRange.upperBound
            let nsRange = NSRange(text.startIndex..<endIndex, in: text)
            attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
            attributedString!.addAttributes([.foregroundColor : Colors.TitleColor, .font : Fonts.robotoBold14], range: nsRange)
            stop = true
        }
        wordIndex += 1
    }

    if let attributedText = attributedString {
       label.attributedText = attributedText
    } else {
       label.text = text
    }
}
```

Comment: thx, but this version have same problem like my code. If text look like "123 123 123 123 123 123" text color changed only for first word. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: My code is supposed to work. I added an alternative solution.